# Getting the userId of another User type in the database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android project that has 2 apps on separate devices. I set up the backend service with Firebase. I have two different type Users, `Rider` and `Driver`. From the RiderApp, I save to the database.

What I am trying to do is retrieve the value I saved to the database.

Firebase was set up as one project with two apps sharing the same google-services.json.

My question is, if I am in the DriverApp, **how do I get the userid of theRiderApp?**

If I put userId = firebaseUser.getUid() -> gets the current driver of the app I am in but how do I get the userId of the RiderApp in order to get this "read Firebase" successful?

Example of Firebase structure:

```js
{
  "Requests": {
    "khVbT88fA8YUmt5qv5LG0OTVZEm1": {
      ".priority": "f81189yp46",
      "destination": {
        "searchBar": "43 Union Street"
      },
      "g": "f81189yp46",
      "l": [
        45.274498,
        -66.0634308
      ]
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "Drivers": {
      "RAFIxzcAYjNNIU15IMIVHfr0CMC2": {
        "email": "driver2@me.com",
        "name": "LizG",
        "password": "zzzzzz",
        "phone": "6532525"
      },
      "vP9r4F2yDWRRuvKjRiQvMEXVuoK2": {
       "email": "driver@me.com",
        "name": "Batman",
        "password": "zzzzzz",
        "phone": "5326598",
        "rates": "0"
      }
    },
    "Riders": {
      "khVbT88fA8YUmt5qv5LG0OTVZEm1": {
        "avatarUrl": "",
        "email": "rider@me.com",
        "name": "Rider",
        "password": "zzzzzz",
        "phone": "5551211",
        "rates": "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UserId = "Users/Riders" current userId
From my DriverApp, I am trying to retrieve the value from "Requests/userId/destination/searchBar

### Edited

```
private void findDriver() {

    final DatabaseReference drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(
            Common.driver_tbl);
    GeoFire gfDrivers = new GeoFire(drivers);

    GeoQuery geoQuery = gfDrivers.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
            Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()), radius);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            // if found
            if (!Common.isDriverFound) {
                Common.isDriverFound = true;
                Common.driverId = key;
                btnRequest.setText("CALL DRIVER");
                //                    Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "Request Sent",
                //                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) { }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) { }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            // if still not found driver, increase distance
            if (!Common.isDriverFound && radius < LIMIT) {
                radius++;
                findDriver();


            } else if (!Common.isDriverFound) {
                Toast.makeText(RiderHome.this, "There are NO available drivers near you.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btnRequest.setText("REQUEST RYYDE");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {}
    });
}
```

**Updated Code**

When run gives a result:
{RBUUID8JNihtbMmvwgcjZVgj2Ku2={driver=wLY5SqTxiLTUhToZdcyRh8uqNKF3, g=f8118dn88t, destination={tapOnMap=Somerset St}, l=[45.2747733, -66.0628253]}}

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests")
            .orderByChild("driver").equalTo(driverId);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String riderDest = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            etDestination.setText(riderDest);
            Log.d(TAG, "riderDest = " + riderDest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I get the userid of theRiderApp?

You cannot unless you create a connection between the rider and the driver. So when you are creating a request, you should also asign to the particular `request` the corresponding driver. Then you can simply query the database to get all data from the request object, including the corresponding driver.

Your changed request node should look like this:

```
"Requests": {
  "khVbT88fA8YUmt5qv5LG0OTVZEm1": {
    ".priority": "f81189yp46",
    "destination": {
      "searchBar": "43 Union Street"
    },
    "g": "f81189yp46",
    "driver": "RAFIxzcAYjNNIU15IMIVHfr0CMC2", //driver id added
    "l": [
      45.274498,
      -66.0634308
    ]
  }
},
```

As you can see, now the request object contains as the key of the node the rider id and as a property the driver id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173564/discussion-between-lizg-and-alex-mamo).